# Get position in array element

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartnew.js

In JavaScript, I am unable to figure out how to use the data object in the function below to get the position of the clicked-on data point (e.g. `third data point in the series`).

Using [chartsNew.js](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js), a popular fork of charts.js, this code shows the value of the datapoint at the mouse click:

```
function fnMouseDownLeft(event,ctx,config,data,other){
    if(other != null){
        window.alert("["+  data.labels[other.v12]+",  "+data.datasets[other.v11].data[other.v12]  +"]");
    }else{
        window.alert("You click Left but not on a data");
    }
}
```

How do I display the clicked element's position in the data series?

[**jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wesn0xm5/)

This seems the most promising but I don't understand the relationship between `data.datasets`, `data.datasets[other]` and `data.datasets[other].data[other]`

```
window.alert("Position: " + data.datasets[other.v11].data[other.v3] );
```

**Here is documentation:**

https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/wiki/100_095_Mouse_Actions

https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/wiki/120_Template_variables#inGraphDataTmpl-annotateLabel

My confusion: `v12` (for a line chart) should display the position of data in the series (which is what I want) but instead it displays the x-axis value for that datapoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

other.v12 seems to do the trick

```
alert(other.v12);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wesn0xm5/1/

Not sure why it's not giving you the series, it does for me.

Comment: The *one* variation I didn't try --- and (looking at it now) an obvious one, too.  Thanks for the help. *The solution is often so easy... in hindsight...*

Comment: Glad I could help, I often fall into the same pitfall. It's like proofreading your own essay and missing the same typos and grammar mistakes over and over.